# Non-typeable control characters to use as separators in text file to be read by line in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, generator, pipeline, separator

I am experimenting with trying to reduce memory usage in restoring a large amount of data saved in a text file on the client's disk to an indexedDB database through using a pipeline of generator functions.

I want the text file to be the concatenation of a large number of JSON strings each with a key that indicates to which object store that string is to be written.

The first generator should read and yield each JSON string and key from the text file one at a time. The second should yield the JSON.parse of that result. I'm not sure yet if a third will be needed, but will iterate over the last one to write to the database.

My question is in this set up, what is a good choice of non-typeable control character or combination of something like that to use as a separator between the JSON strings?  Some of the strings contain user input from at least one content editable division and I want to ensure that nothing the user supplies could result in the separation of one of the JSON strings.

Thank you.

**Alternative Solution**

After reading more about encoding and escaping and hurting my little brain, I think this approach of using some type of non-typeable delimiter should not be pursued further and is too risky.

A better approach may be to build an array of small objects, as each JSON string is concatenated to the string that will eventually become the text file, that contains each JSON string's length and key identifying where in the database it belongs.  The array will be placed at the front of the text file as a JSON string also, followed by an end-of-array identifier which can be any text that wouldn't appear in that array of objects--and that I can control and is independent of unknown user input.  This way it can be read in first, by finding the first occurrence of that identifier before any user input is read, and parsed to extract each JSON string from the file without the need for any delimeters.

In retrospect, my first thought that lead to this question was rather stupid.

Comment: Maybe use a "normal" character like ";" and escape it when the the user types that in your json? Otherwise someone who knows the delimiter can always break your code. Or use something the user doesn't need to type and strip that from the json

Comment: @AramBrecker Thanks. How do you dynamically escape a normal character in javascript?

Comment: I'd go for a regex approach: https://jsfiddle.net/f95vbrjy/20/ Not sure if the split mechanic is suitable for you, as your strings will probably tend to get very long